# how to display table formatted data in java script popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi  how to display table formatted data in java script popup.
 it is possible to display table formatted data in java script popup. in asp.net using C# language.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display formatted tables in a regular JS alert box.
The alert function opens an OS\ web browser indignant window that dose not display HTML.

you alternative is to use any available modal dialog JS plugin that will allow you to create something similar.

here is an example using jQuery's modal dialog with a table:
[JS FIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UAJeA/2/)

html:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an [extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)
and u can use it like this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
        Hello World!
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
    PopupControlID="Panel1"
    DropShadow="true" 
    OkControlID="OkButton" 
    CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel3" >
        <Animations>
            <OnShowing> ..  </OnShowing>
            <OnShown>   ..  </OnShown>    
            <OnHiding>  ..  </OnHiding>            
            <OnHidden>  ..  </OnHidden>            
        </Animations>
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

and whatever u put in that panel will be it popup.